# Merge mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a number of queries with slightly different requirements and will be used with load testing so lowering the number of query calls the better. I thought there must be a way to rearrange the queries into one big one.

The following are very simplified versions of the kind of data features I'm utilising

Query 1 (Limit scenario):

```
    SELECT SUM(f_total_ftg>=2) as ftg_2_plus FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM results WHERE (f_player1='arcos' OR f_player2='arcos') 
    AND (f_player1='skromnuy' OR f_player2='skromnuy') 
    AND f_total_ftg IS NOT NULL AND f_datetime < '2020-07-26 00:54:00' 
    ORDER BY f_datetime DESC LIMIT 10) as x
```

Query 2 (No limit scenario):

```
SELECT SUM(f_total_ftg>=2) as ftg_2_plus FROM 
(SELECT * FROM results WHERE (f_player1='arcos' OR f_player2='arcos') 
AND (f_player1='skromnuy' OR f_player2='skromnuy') 
AND f_total_ftg IS NOT NULL AND f_datetime < '2020-07-26 00:54:00' 
ORDER BY f_datetime DESC) as x
```

Query 3 (Date range scenario):

```
SELECT SUM(f_total_ftg>=2) as ftg_2_plus FROM 
(SELECT * FROM results WHERE (f_player1='arcos' OR f_player2='arcos') 
AND (f_player1='skromnuy' OR f_player2='skromnuy') 
AND f_total_ftg IS NOT NULL AND f_datetime BETWEEN '2020-07-26 00:54:00' - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND '2020-07-26 00:54:00' 
ORDER BY f_datetime DESC) as x
```

I'm not sure how i'd order my sub queries to accommodate these scenarios.

I'd want 3 columns from this:

```
ftg_2_plus_no_limit
ftg_2_plus_no_limit
ftg_2_plus_date_range
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the cte(Common Table Expressions) to solve the problem.

```
with cte_base as (
SELECT * FROM results WHERE 
    (f_player1='arcos' OR f_player2='arcos') 
    AND (f_player1='skromnuy' OR f_player2='skromnuy') 
    AND f_total_ftg IS NOT NULL
    AND f_total_ftg >=2
    ORDER BY f_datetime DESC)
SELECT (SELECT SUM(f_total_ftg) FROM cte_base 
where f_datetime < '2020-07-26 00:54:00' limit 10) as ftg_2_plus_limit,
(SELECT SUM(f_total_ftg) FROM cte_base 
where f_datetime < '2020-07-26 00:54:00') as ftg_2_plus_no_limit,
SELECT SUM(f_total_ftg) FROM cte_base 
where f_datetime BETWEEN '2020-07-26 00:54:00' - INTERVAL 1 DAY 
AND '2020-07-26 00:54:00') as ftg_2_plus_date_range
```

Answer (score 0):

You could merge your queries in to one using a cross join and tweaking conditions on `sum()`

```
select r1.ftg_2_plus_limit,
       sum(r.f_total_ftg>=2 and f_datetime < '2020-07-26 00:54:00') ftg_2_plus_no_limit,
       sum(r.f_total_ftg>=2 and f_datetime between '2020-07-26 00:54:00' - interval 1 day and '2020-07-26 00:54:00') ftg_2_plus_date_range
from results r
cross join (
    select sum(f_total_ftg>=2) ftg_2_plus_limit
    from results
    where (f_player1='arcos' or f_player2='arcos') 
        and (f_player1='skromnuy' or f_player2='skromnuy') 
        and f_total_ftg is not null
        and f_datetime < '2020-07-26 00:54:00' 
    order by f_datetime desc 
    limit 10
) r1
where (f_player1='arcos' or f_player2='arcos') 
    and (f_player1='skromnuy' or f_player2='skromnuy') 
    and f_total_ftg is not null
```